# Hair as fair as flax?

Tags: meaning

I read this simile in a poem and was wondering what it symbolizes. I have no experience with flax so I don't know what it might mean. Is flax yellow or brown? A Google search shows me images of both.

Comment: Hair is often described using "flaxen", defined as "pale yellow" (https://www.google.com/#q=flaxen). For images: https://www.google.com/search?q=flaxen&biw=1573&bih=819&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPo7Xgn6bQAhXI7YMKHTQ6CwkQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.1

Comment: [In the right context,](https://www.google.com/#q=flax+textile) yes. [Otherwise](https://www.google.com/search?q=flax), no.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Comment: Hint: brown hair is not usually described as 'fair'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various views as to whether using flaxen as colour is related to the seeds or the 'dressed' fibres of the flax plant.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax_(color)):

> Flax or Flaxen is a **pale yellowish-gray** color named after **flax seeds**. An early use of "flaxen" to describe hair color appears in David Copperfield, by Charles Dickens: Mr. Omer's granddaughter, Minnie, is described as "a pretty little girl with long, flaxen, curling hair." The first recorded use of flax as a color name in English was in 1915

However [Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flaxen) says it's the fibers after dressing ( which is part of the processing before making into thread).

> adj.
>   2. of the **pale yellowish** color of **dressed flax**.
>   [1510–20]

Personally, I suspect the **colour of fibers** makes more sense, especially for hair.

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Dressing the flax is the process of removing the straw from the fibers. Dressing consists of three steps: breaking, scutching, and heckling. The breaking breaks up the straw.  [...].
>   Heckling is pulling the fiber through various sizes of heckling combs or heckles. A heckle is a bed of "nails"—sharp, long-tapered, tempered, polished steel pins driven into wooden blocks at regular spacing.

Here is a picture of the fibers being heckled ...

[image]

And here is a picture of flax seeds ...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Shakespeare has something to say on this in *Twelfth Night*:

**Sir Toby Belch:** *Then hadst thou had an excellent head of hair.*

**Sir Andrew Aguecheek:** *Why, would that have mended my hair?*

```
                                 --0--
```

**Sir Toby Belch:** *Past question; for thou seest it will not curl by nature.*

**Sir Andrew Aguecheek:** *But it becomes me well enough, does't not?*

```
                                  --0--
```

**Sir Toby Belch:** *Excellent; it hangs like* ***flax*** *on a distaff; and I hope to see a housewife take thee between her legs and spin it off*

```
                                --0--
```

I had the great good fortune to see a number of stage productions of *Twelfth Night*. The character of Sir Andrew Aguecheek, bewigged with straight and unyielding **flaxen** blond hair down to his shoulder, was perfectly suited to the half-wit that Shakespeare so memorably created.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective "fair" means, among other things, light hue or colour, so if the hair is "as fair as flax", it is referring to the pale-coloured flax fabric. Yes, similar to blonde.

Comment: So similar to blonde?

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.

Comment: A word that describes very light blond hair is "towheaded."

Comment: @Airymouse One of the definitions of 'tow' from the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tow) is **The coarse and broken part of flax or hemp prepared for spinning.** So 'towheaded' is pretty much the same comparison as 'flaxen haired'